# Unable to delete Dropbox folder from my local hard disk

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox

I have installed Dropbox app on Mac. This created a folder named "Dropbox" in my home folder.

I copied a large folder into this Dropbox folder.

The syncing of this folder is taking a lot of time so I have unlinked the Dropbox folder from Dropbox app (Dropbox app preferences -> Account -> Unlink the dropbox). Now when I try to delete this "Dropbox" folder I get the below error:

```
  The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. 
For each item, choose File > Get Info, make sure “Locked” is deselected, and then check the Sharing & Permissions section. 
When you are sure the items are unlocked and not designated as Read Only or No Access, try again.
```

I have seen the 'Get Info' and see that the folder has 'locked' checkbox not ticked and also in users I see that I have read&write access

I also restarted my Mac but I still get the same error

How do I delete this folder(including all its sub-folders). How can I force delete this folder?

I am able to move the folder to Bin but I cannot delete the folder from Bin. I was doing 'Delete immediately' option and the folder is not getting deleted. How do I get the free space on my hard drive back?

Comment: Is the Dropbox applet still running?

Comment: I quit the Dropbox app but did not uninstall the app

Comment: @nohillside: I have uninstalled the Dropbox app(by moving the Dropbox app to bin) and restarted the MAC. But I am still not able to delete the "Dropbox" folder. As an admin, I want to just delete the folder from my local hard disk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folder is in the Trash now:

- Open Terminal
- `cd ~/.Trash`
- `rm -r Dropbox`

If the folder isn't in Trash, skip the second step.

Comment: I get the message asking me `override rwxrwxrwx mymacusername(firstpostcommenter)/staff uchg for somefile ?` How do I give yes to all?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter That's a bit unspecific so I hesitate to say yes without knowing what it concerns (but in general, and assuming the `cd` worked correctly, "yes"). If it doesn't work, please add the result of `ls -le@d ~/.Trash/Dropbox`.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x@ 3 macusername  staff  96 Jun  7 17:16 Foldername
 com.dropbox.attrs 26

Comment: @firstpostcommenter Foldername is "Dropbox"?

Comment: I was trying to delete the large folder inside the Dropbox folder. For "Dropbox" folder when I run the given command then I get `drwx------@ 4 mymacusername  staff  128 Jun  7 17:14 Dropbox/
 com.apple.FinderInfo  32 
 0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity`

Comment: I want to give yes to all because they are many files so even I press enter key for a long time I will not be able to delete all subfolders easily because I get too many questions in the format `override rwxrwxrwx mymacusername(firstpostcommenter)/staff uchg for somefile ?`

Comment: @firstpostcommenter use `rm -rf Dropbox` then